# Что должен уметь системный администратор?

Tags: работа, администрирование

Хочу узнать, какие есть разновидности данной профессии и чему должен научится человек, чтобы быть системным администратором?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы классифицировал по различной специфике работы:

1.Эникейщик (без обид), офисный админ (по-моему для малого офиса самое то), который умеет все, и программы, и линуксы, и винды, и бегает помогает товарищам:)

2.Системщики-настройщики, товарищи, которые работают исключительно с сетевым оборудованием, при этом делятся на:

> Проектировщики
>
> Специалисты по настройке
>
> Специалисты по безопасности
>
> И так далее, тут их может быть, очень
> много

3.Системщики-аудиторы, распространенная практика за границей, которые проводят анализ стойкости системы от и до.

Собственно системный администратор, это служащий предприятия, который отвечает за:

1. Организацию и поддержку работы информационной системы предприятия
2. Обеспечение безопасности и сохранности данных предприятия
3. (можно в 2) Выполнение систематического бэкапа данных
4. Устранение неполадок
5. Ведение документации

Нужно выбирать область и работать с ней. Только каждая из этих областей имеет под-области. В идеале вы должны уметь все, что касается этих областей.

Например:

1. Установка и настройка ОС: Linux, Windows (толковая настройка, а не поставил и забыл)
2. Установка и настройка Серверных ОС, внедрение технологий автоматизации, бэкапов, DNS, HTTP, FTP, DB, Mail - серверов
3. Настройка сети на ОС, на активном оборудовании
4. Настройка роутинга, NAT
5. Настройка безопасности на основе встроеных в ОС фаерволов
6. Настройка хардверных фаерволов (например Juniper, Cisco, Check Point)
7. Установка и настройка VPN (IKE, IPSec), VoIP (+ защита)
8. Системы мониторинга, системы IPS, IDS

Список настолько длинный, что для одного человека не под силу. Чисто физически.

Comment: Я бы добавил сюда вот что. Когда мы внедряем наш продукт, кто-то из сотрудников заказчика становится его администратором. Это касается не только заказных разработок. Всегда могут оказаться специализированные продукты, требующие администрирования.

Answer (score 4):

Обычно их классифицируют по роду занятий (боюсь ошибиться с названиями но попробую):

- сетевой инженер (его дело вся сеть т.е. свичи, роутеры, витуха, розетки)
- Инженер по безопасности (сетевые экраны иногда прокси сервера, антивирусы, HIPS, ограничение доступа к информации, шифрование и др.)
- Админ серверов (обычно линуксоид и поднимает их на FreeBSD его дело поддержание работоспособности и бекапы)
- Админ домена (поддерживает AD, вносит пользователей и т.д.)
- Администратор АО (не знаю как еще назвать, он бегает везде и ставит винду, проги, решает мелкие проблемы, иногда имеет сервер чтобы автоматизировать свою работу)
- Тех поддержка (иногда их записывают и сюда, вся работа заключается в помощи по работе с пользователями, иногда совмещен с предыдущим)

Ну и чтобы быть хорошим админом надо любить это. Компы, протяжку витухи, автоматизацию рутины. Когда это доставляет удовольствие качество работы, даже при не знании мелочей поднимается во много раз, ну а мелочи узнаются в процессе.

Comment: В ETH работает 2500 сетевых инженеров, как нам рассказывали.
Думаю, что и тут все не достаточно полно описано, там в каждом можно выделить по несколько подпунктов. Но в целом, логично.

Comment: Я не стал выделать подпункты т.к. тыщи их

Answer (score 4):

Главное чему должен научиться сисадмин - ответственности. Главная функция админа - обеспечивать беспрерывную работу ИТ инфраструктуры, технологии не так важны.

Падающий сервер это не "ах, блин, забыл одну галочку поставить". Это может остановить работу десятков и сотен людей которые будут ооооочень злы. Лучше уметь админить что-нибудь одно но знать как это делать в совершнестве, чтобы все падения, перезагрузки серверов и т.п. происходили в нерабочее время, а данные на общих ресурсах никогда не терялись.  100500 раз я видел студентов, которые печатают в баше комманды быстрее чем я успеваю их читать, но у всех у них постоянно не работает толи почта толи днс... Если у вас всё всегда будет работать - вы будете лучшим :)

А вообще - не ходите вы ребята в админы. Администрирование по большому счёту всего навсего сервис, обслуга того что написали программисты. Несомненно админство это очень важно, но если вы любите компы и хотите работать с ними - попробуйте всё же программирование.

Comment: Также можно сказать "Программирование по большому счёту всего навсего сервис, обслуга того что придумали менеджеры"

Comment: Сказать то можно, вот только это не правда :) Точнее почти всегда не правда. Программист делает продукт, а админ предоставляет услуги. Иногда, конечно, бывает так, что программист только чинит багло и добавляет новенькие отчётики в готовую софтину... и это не менее печально чем админство. Подумай, хочешь ли ты в 30 лет лазить под стол к менеджеру, втыкать сетевой кабель?

Comment: Я добавлю в свой ответ то чего тут нет)

Answer (score 1):

Увы (к сожалению или нет некоторых коллег) системное администрирование совершенно изменилось в своей основе.
Это уже давно (если конечно мы говорим о серьезном предприятии) не "бегание", "ставление" винды или линукса, обслуга свичей маршрутизаторов и тем более вит пары и розеток.
Выделю 2 главных аспекта

Пункт-1

ФУНДАМЕНТАЛЬНОЕ ЗНАНИЕ (И УМЕНИЕ НА ПРАКТИКЕ ПРИМЕНЯТЬ) практически ВСЕХ сетевых протоколов и сервисов (как ремесленное применение - основа понимания их работы в целевых программных продуктах-веб-сервера-опер системы-прикладное ПО)
Упрощая можно сказать, что сегодня надо не ВТЫКАТЬ а ПОНИМАТЬ как работает вся сетевая инфраструктрура.

Пункт-2

ПРОГРАММНАЯ СРЕДА ЭКСПЛУАТИРУЕМЫХ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ, это уже не банальное умение написания скриптов, запросов, минипрог для получения результата, а прежде всего комплесное изучение и знание ОСНОВ (иногда зачастую и большего)языков программирования, интерпретаторов, программных технологий - куда не кинь всюду С++, PHP, Java, Ajax, различные СУБД, WEB-технологии и тому нет конца. Одни лишь системы мониторинга требуют серьезного знания всего вышеперечисленного, а о системах безопасности особенно от инсайдеров (например в банках)и говорить нечего...

- ОБЩЕЕ

А в целом все это так или иначе начинает пересекаться---сложно сегодня представить себе программиста, который ничего не понимает в операционных системах (еще 10 лет назад-это было практически нормой), также вызовет удивление (если не более) сисадмин не способный написать банальный HTML-текст или сценарий на PHP,PL,PowerShell,Vba.
Но самое потрясающее во всем этом ЧТО СЛАВА БОГУ!!!! - Ассемблер как был так и остается ассемблером----вот когда и тут ПРОИЗОЙДЕТ НЕЧТО, тО ДА!!!!!:))

Answer (score 0):

На мой взягляд обычный сис. админ в первую очередь должен знать предметную область отдела, предприятия, который он поддерживает и тот набор ПО, которое используется в работе.

Comment: Тогда это будет эникейщик. Системный администратор это комплексное понятие.

Comment: Знание предметной области и умение нажаить нужную кнопку - не одно и тоже.

Comment: А зачем админу знание предметной области? Вот, например, какое-нибудь машиностроительное промышленное предприятие.. зачем ему знать как там какие-нибудь турбины работают? Ему надо обеспечить работоспособность инфраструктуры, а не в тонкости отдела лезть.

Answer (score 0):

Все эти классификации. )
Я устанавливаю по всему офису системы(винда.), настраиваю ПО, сеть тоже я делаю, как писали выше: свитчи, роутеры, и всё что с этим связано. Обслуживание ОПЗ и БестЗвит. Безопасность ещё.
В общем всё что только можно назвать администрированием.
Только называют меня все программистом. )